# Dynamic JSON field create with java

Tags: java, json

<del>I need to dynamically create a JSON file using core Java.</del>

<del>The field number and file name is up to user to choose. For instance one JSON may look like this:</del>

```
{
    "lang": "python",
    "file": "class.py",
    "args": "arg"
}
```

or maybe

```
{
    "Name": "python",
    "Class": "XII",
    "Roll": 07,
    "phone": 9874658393
}
```

<del>Any idea how to do this project?</del>

Comment: What have you tried so far?  Have you run into any particular errors or problems? You need to be a lot more specific with your question in order to get good answers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First off all you need a json libary for Java.

So if you're using this [json libary](http://www.java2s.com/Code/Jar/o/Downloadorgjsonjar.htm) you can do something like:

```
JSONObject obj = new JSONObject();
obj.put("lang", "python");
obj.put("file", "class.py");
```

`obj.toString()` will return `{"file":"class.py","lang":"python"}`